# Debugging error IDA Cant find file

Tags: debugging, 64-bit, reverse-engineering, ida

I am getting an error for some reason:

> 'Can't initialize help system. File name 'ida.hlp', reason: can't find file.
>       Press enter to exit'

I don't know where to get the file from.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently windows 8.1 doesn't support the "Windows Help format", Just needed to install a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

you must remove the line about the old version of idapro in the "System variables"
[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Amgn.png)